# How to initialize a a struct of structs inside a header file in C?

Tags: c, header, struct, initialization, gnu

I am trying to port some old code over from a 20 year old DOS system to a GNU Linux system.  In several of their header files, (which are included all over the place), they have structs of structs that they declare and initialize.  I am getting warnings when I compile with the way the legacy code was written.  Any tips on how I can get this to work with staying inside the same header file?

The following is a simplified example I made of what they are doing.

```
struct A
{

    struct B  temp1;
    struct C  temp2;
};

struct B
{

    int temp3;
    int temp4; 
    int temp5;
};

struct C
{

    int temp6;
    int temp7;
    int temp8;
};


//These are the variables in how they are related to the initialization below

//struct A test_one = {{temp3,temp4,temp5},{temp6,temp7,temp8}};

struct A test_one = {{1,2,3},{4,5,6}};
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't instantiate any structures in header files. If you do a different instance will be created in each C file you include the header in which is usually not the desired effect.

In a C file to do this you would have to do the following.

```
void foo(){
struct A parent;
struct B child_b;
struct C child_c;

child_b.temp3 = 3;
child_b.temp4 = 4;
child_b.temp5 = 5;

child_c.temp6 = 6;
child_c.temp7 = 7;
child_c.temp8 = 8;

parent.temp1 = child_b;
parent.temp2 = child_c;
}
```

I would strong consider making helper functions similar to this

```
void initB(struct B* s, int x, int y, int z){
    s->temp3 = x;
    s->temp4 = y;
    s->temp5 = z;
}
```

If you would like the keep the array initialization syntax then consider using a union.

Comment: Especially as they are not declared static.  I know somebody who did something similar a few years back, instead of complaining, for each reference to the multiply defined variable, the linker seemed to use one of the instances at random.

Comment: @JeremyP: you'd have to *declare* the variable `extern` in the header file and instantiate and initialize it in exactly one compilation unit.

Comment: I actually tried doing this same thing inside a C file instead of the header and I am getting the same warnings.  I guess I should re-phrase the original question to "How to initialize a a struct of structs in C?". The warnings I am getting are a "missing bracket around initializer" warning along with a "near initializtion for ...." warning.

Comment: @ Jens Gustedt:  I know that is what you are meant to do, but this person was *defining* the variable in the header and including it in several places.  This meant that multiple variables with the same name and external linkage existed in the linked binary (in C a variable defined with no storage specifier is treated as an `extern` by default).

Comment: So I ask again, if you were initializing "struct A test_one" how would you physically write it out?  Because this -> "{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}" is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Declare struct B and C before A, i.e. :

```
struct B { int temp3; int temp4; int temp5; };
struct C { int temp6; int temp7; int temp8; };
struct A { struct B temp1; struct C temp2; };
```

Comment: My bad, I was just making up a simple example.  In the actual code "struct A" is declared after B and C.

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is not compilable, since it is illegal to use incomplete type to declare `struct` members. I assume that you simply misarranged your `struct` definitions: the definitions for `B` and `C` should go first.

Having said that, the only warning this code can generate is the "warning" from linker that might complain about multiple definitions of the same object `test_one`, if the header file is included in multiple translation units. In C this is technically illegal, although many compilers allow it as a popular compiler extension.

So, what "warnings" are you getting?

Comment: I am getting a "missing bracket around initializer" warning along with a "near initializtion for ...." warning.